# MySQL formatting results based on table name and multiple table data

Tags: php, mysql

I am coming into this project and have a little MySQL background to do basic SELECTs and INSERTs and whatnot. But, this is making me beat my head against the wall.

I have a typical user information table in MySQL:

```
USERS
+-------+----------+---------+-----+
|user_id|first_name|last_name|email|
+-------+----------+---------+-----+
 1       tim        jones     tj@acme.com
 2       sarah      peteres   sp@acme.com
 3       larry      doe       ld@acme.com
```

Then I have multiple product tables:

```
PRODUCTS_ONE
+-------+-------+---------+----------+--------------+
|prod_id|user_id|prod_name|prod_width|prod_ship_date|
+-------+-------+---------+----------+--------------+
 1       1       bowl      nine       1-1-16
 2       1       fork      one        1-2-16
 3       2       plate     eleven     1-3-16

PRODUCTS_TWO
+-------+-------+----------+--------+--------------+
|prod_id|user_id|prod_state|prod_job|prod_ship_date|
+-------+-------+----------+--------+--------------+
 1       3       maine      min      1-1-16
 2       2       texas      max      1-2-16
 3       1       ohio       min      1-1-16
```

I have 15 total PRODUCT tables that all have prod_id, users_id, and prod_ship_date. The other fields might all be different based on what product table they are in. But, all the different PRODUCT tables have those three common fields.

What I am trying to accomplish is to get a list of USER info and PRODUCT info for products that match a certain ship date.

I want to find all the users and what product table and product id they are getting on a certain date.

So, if I searched on a ship date of 1-1-16, I would get something like:

```
+----------------+-----------+-------------+-----------+
|users.first_name|users.email|product_table|products_id|
+----------------+-----------+-------------+-----------+
 tim              tj@acme.com one,two       1,3
 larry            ld@acme.com one           3
```

If I searched on a ship date of 1-2-16, I would get something like:

```
+----------------+-----------+-------------+-----------+
|users.first_name|users.email|product_table|products_id|
+----------------+-----------+-------------+-----------+
 tim              tj@acme.com one           2
 sarah            sp@acme.com two           2
```

I hope this all makes sense. Unfortunately, I cannot change the structure or layout of the various product tables due to legacy issues.

I just can't figure out the MySQL statement to use to get something like this.

The above results will be used for reporting purposes.

Comment: Because you want the table name in the result, you are doing a form of a pivot. One way to do this is to do a subquery using `UNION` and an outer query that uses `GROUP_CONCAT()` to return your csv by user.

Comment: check out the final query in my answer, it should give you the desired result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could write a query like this:

```
select first_name,email,prod_id,group_concat(product_table) as product_table from (
select u.user_id ,first_name,email,prod_id, 'one' as product_table from users u join products_one p on u.user_id = p.user_id where prod_ship_date = '2016-01-01 00:00:00'
union
select u.user_id,first_name,email,prod_id, 'two' as product_table  from users u join products_two p on u.user_id = p.user_id where prod_ship_date = '2016-01-01 00:00:00'
) a
```

group by a.user_id

order by user_id,product_table

and so on.

With the second group concat and order by

```
select first_name,email,group_concat(prod_id),group_concat(product_table) as product_table from (
select u.user_id ,first_name,email,prod_id, 'one' as product_table from users u join products_one p on u.user_id = p.user_id where prod_ship_date = '2016-01-01 00:00:00'
union
select u.user_id,first_name,email,prod_id, 'two' as product_table  from users u join products_two p on u.user_id = p.user_id where prod_ship_date = '2016-01-01 00:00:00'
) a


group by a.user_id

order by user_id,product_table
```

Check out this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/70b8e/42/0)

Comment: The OP gave the desired format of `users.first_name|users.email|product_table|products_id` where `product_table` & `products_id` are csv's grouped by the `user_id`. So how does this meet that desired outcome?

Comment: @davejal So, this is sort of getting me close. This returns most of the data that I am needing. But, it duplicates user id's if the a certain user has more than one product. I am trying to concatenate the product id's by user. I thought I gave examples of my desired output at the end of my question. If I can improve, please let me know.

Comment: No I made a mistake, didn't read the last part good enough, working on the final part

Comment: I edited my query and added an sqlfiddle for you to test

Comment: @davejal This is really close. I added a second GROUP_CONCAT to the main SELECT query: GROUP_CONCAT(prod_id) AS prod_id_list. This now shows all products tables that a user is in and the prod_id from those tables. But, it seems that these are in no particular order. Do you know if the there is away to order by table name but still keep the prod_id's matched correctly? Thank you!

Comment: I tired that. What I am wanting is for the product_table column to be "one,two" instead of "two,one". I am playing around with ORDER BY but just can't see to get it right. If I just do a simple ORDER BY product_table then the prod_ids do not match.

Comment: click on the sqlfiddle

Comment: Very close. Did you see where I add the second GROUP_CONCAT: GROUP_CONCAT(prod_id) AS prod_id_list?

Comment: select first_name,email,group_concat(product_table) as product_table,group_concat(prod_id) as prod_id_list from (
select u.user_id ,first_name,email,prod_id, 'one' as product_table from users u join products_one p on u.user_id = p.user_id where prod_ship_date = '2016-01-01 00:00:00'
union
select u.user_id,first_name,email,prod_id, 'two' as product_table  from users u join products_two p on u.user_id = p.user_id where prod_ship_date = '2016-01-01 00:00:00'
) a


group by a.user_id

order by user_id,product_table

Comment: I will check further tommorow, need some sleep

Comment: In the end this is what got me 99.9% of the way there. I had an issue with the sort order that I could not figure out. But, in the end it was really not a big deal to not have the prod_tables sorted.

Comment: great it helped partially, I got caught in work here today, if I have some spare time this week I'll update you